# Create Github pull request first commit and last commit?

Tags: github, pull-request

**1)** how do i create a Github pull request from first commit and last commit?

**2)** and how do i generate/download a patch from that pull request?

Is it possible to do in Github?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 ) creating a pull request,refer this link :-

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/

2) Every pull-request on Github can be downloaded as a beautiful mail-patch, just by appending ".patch" to the pr URL.

E.g., from: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/296

To: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/296.patch

This will generate a mail-formatted patch file, that is a little different from an usual patch file: It has e-mail metadata.
After downloaded, apply the result patch using: $ git am 296.patch
refer this link:-https://docs.moodle.org/dev/How_to_create_a_patch#Creating_a_patch_using_Git

Comment: Regarding 1), but how do i create a pull-request between 2 Revisions (from my first revision/commit and my last revision/commit) ? Thanks

Comment: Just add a new commit to the branch used in the pull request and push the branch to GitHub. The pull request will automatically be updated with the additional commit. If people want to see only where your branch was merged in (and not the additional commits), they can use git log --first-parent to only view the merge commit in the log

Comment: i see i can compare between commits using the SHA code... But can i safe or download this pull-request as a patch or something? I don't have a Collaborator connected. I just have to send them a Git patch...

Comment: I think you can send the patches as emails Use gmail as the smtp server...but I am not sure .....................................read this link:-http://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email

To use git send-email to send your patches through the GMail SMTP server, edit ~/.gitconfig to specify your account settings:

Comment: @Meez refer this link also :-http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/HowToUseGitSendEmail/

Comment: But it will make live much easier if i add a Collaborator or not? To the Collaborator i can make the pull-request and they can download the patch, isn't it? thanks!

Comment: @Meez yes , it will make easy when you add collaborator ,,,If you find my answer useful,,,you can accept my answer so that I can get more reputation

Comment: actually [this](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/How_to_create_a_patch#Creating_a_patch_using_Git) was exactly what i was looking for :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Meez thankz...I have attched this link in my answer also ,so It will be useful to others also...:)